# Keras - How to remove useless dimension without hurting the computation graph?

Tags: keras

While generating a deep learning model, I used `K.squeeze` function to squeeze useless dimension when the first two dimensions were None shape.

```py
import keras.backend as K
>>> K.int_shape(user_input_for_TD)
(None, None, 1, 32)
>>> K.int_shape(K.squeeze(user_input_for_TD, axis=-2))
(None, None, 32)
```

However, this gives below error, It seems like `K.squeeze` function hurts the computation graph, is there any solution to escape from this issue? Maybe that function does not support calculating gradients, which isn't differentiable.

```py
File "/home/sundong/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1325, in build_map
    node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Below code block is the whole code block which causes that error.

```py
user_embedding_layer = Embedding(
            input_dim=len(self.data.visit_embedding),
            output_dim=32,
            weights=[np.array(list(self.data.visit_embedding.values()))],
            input_length=1,
            trainable=False)
...
all_areas_lstm = LSTM(1024, return_sequences=True)(all_areas_rslt)   # (None, None, 1024)
user_input_for_TD = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 0:1])(multiple_inputs)  # (None, None, 1) 
user_input_for_TD = TimeDistributed(user_embedding_layer)(user_input_for_TD) # (None, None, 1, 32) 
user_input_for_TD = K.squeeze(user_input_for_TD, axis=-2) # (None, None, 32) 
aggre_threeway_inputs = Concatenate()([user_input_for_TD, all_areas_lstm]) # should be (None, None, 1056) 
threeway_encoder = TimeDistributed(ThreeWay(output_dim=512))
three_way_rslt = threeway_encoder(aggre_threeway_inputs) # should be (None, None, 512) 
logits = Dense(365, activation='softmax')(three_way_rslt) # should be (None, None, 365)
self.model = keras.Model(inputs=multiple_inputs, outputs=logits)
```

By removing below two lines (by not making it go through the embedding layer) , the code works without any issues. In this case, dimension of `aggre_threeway_inputs = Concatenate()([user_input_for_TD, all_areas_lstm])` is (None, None, 1025).

```py
user_input_for_TD = TimeDistributed(user_embedding_layer)(user_input_for_TD)
user_input_for_TD = K.squeeze(user_input_for_TD, axis=-2)
```

Comment: You mean `np.squeeze`?

Comment: @HaBom That's a good pointer, is there any equivalent function in Keras?

Comment: you need to put your squeeze function inside a Lambda layer, you can't put tf operations directly into outputs of Keras layers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using the `Lambda` layer with indexing, instead of `K.squeeze` function.

```py
from keras.layers import Lambda
>>> K.int_shape(user_input_for_TD)
(None, None, 1, 32)
>>> K.int_shape(Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 0, :])(user_input_for_TD))
(None, None, 32)
```