# Global operator along a single dimension in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dimension-reduction

Let's say I have a dataset comprising greyscale videos. The length and size of each video can vary so I am representing the data in three dimensions via the following shape:

| Batch size | time | y | x | channels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| None | None | None | None | 1 |

I want to extract features (say 16 of them) from the temporal dimension while keeping the same spatial dimensions, which would give me the following output shape:

| Batch size | y | x | filters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| None | None | None | 16 |

Notably, the shape of the data has been reduced by one dimension. In my head, I should be able to accomplish this with a Conv3D operator (feature generation) followed by some aggregating operation (global/average pooling or some linear operator) over the time dimension only. The resulting shape would be (None, 1, None, None, 16) which I believe I could reduce to (None, None, None, 16) using [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393031/keras-how-to-remove-useless-dimension-without-hurting-the-computation-graph)

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to apply any of Keras's global operators along a single dimension. Since the size of the time dimension is unknown, I cannot specify the window size (unknown, 1, 1) for a [MaxPooling](https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/max_pooling3d/) or [convolutional](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution3d/) layer that would span the entire time dimension. On the other hand, the [GlobalMaxPooling](https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/global_max_pooling3d/) layer doesn't accept an argument for specifying which dimensions to operate on.

Do I have to implement some complicated custom layer for this, or does a solution already exist? I've taken a look at the Reshape layer with MaxPooling1D, but I run into the same problem of not knowing the size of the x and y dimensions to reassemble the spatial structure after the pooling operation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do something like following if you don't want using custom layer:

```
x = Input(shape=(Batch_size, time, y, x, 1))
# Process data wrt time and spaciall info, as many layer as you want
x = Conv3D(filters_num_0, kernel_size_0, strides=1, padding="same", activation=activation_0)(x) # (Batch_size, time, y, x, filters_num_0)
x = Conv3D(filters_num_1, kernel_size_1, strides=1, padding="same", activation=activation_1)(x) # (Batch_size, time, y, x, filters_num_1)
# # Aggregate channel info
x = Conv3D(1, kernel_size_2, strides=1, padding="same", activation=activation_2)(x) # (Batch_size, time, y, x, 1)
# Reshape for dimension reduce
x = Reshape(target_shape=(Batch_size, y, x, time))(x) 
# Aggregate time info
x = Conv2D(16, kernel_size_3, strides=1, padding="same", activation=activation_3 ) # (Batch_size, y, x, 16)
```

Using custom layer to doing for global average pool across time:

```
class GlobalAvgPoolAcrossTime(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GlobalAvgPoolAcrossTime, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    # (Batch_size, time, y, x, channels) -> (Batch_size, 1, y, x, channels)
    def call(self, inputs):
        return keras.backend.mean(inputs, axis=1, keepdims=True)

x = Input(shape=(Batch_size, time, y, x, 1))
# Process data wrt time and spaciall info, as many layer as you want
x = Conv3D(filters_num_0, kernel_size_0, strides=1, padding="same", activation=activation_0)(x) # (Batch_size, time, y, x, filters_num_0)
x = Conv3D(filters_num_1, kernel_size_1, strides=1, padding="same", activation=activation_1)(x) # (Batch_size, time, y, x, filters_num_1)
x = GlobalAvgPoolAcrossTime()(x) # (Batch_size, 1, y, x, filters_num_1)
# Reshape for dimension reduce
x = Reshape(target_shape=(Batch_size, y, x, filters_num_1))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, kernel_size_2, strides=1, padding="same", activation=activation_3 ) # (Batch_size, y, x, 16)
```

Comment: Sending the features to one instead of the timepoints to one is a neat idea that I never considered. I'm not sure how it would affect the model's performance but it's worth a try. I actually like your second idea better, though. I had no idea custom Keras layers were so easy to make. I'm going to leave this quesion open until the end of the week so that other people can contribute their solutions, but I'll accept your answer later this week after giving the custom pooling layer a try. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: @Anthony no problem, always glad to help : ), let me know if I miss anything after you try.

Comment: @Anthony so did you try it out? what's the result?